# Positioning new image like previous image in MS word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to replace an image in a MS Word header using this:

```
For Each tmp In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
    If tmp.Type = msoPicture Then
        Set dShape = tmp
    End If
Next
Dim w, h, t, l As Single
Dim lic As Long
Dim rhp As WdRelativeHorizontalPosition
Dim rvp As WdRelativeVerticalPosition

dShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
dShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin

With dShape
    w = .Width
    h = .Height
    t = .Top
    l = .Left
    lic = .LayoutInCell
End With

Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture("C:\aa.jpg", False, True, l, t, w, h)
shp.RelativeVerticalPosition = rvp
shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = rhp
shp.LayoutInCell = lic

dShape.Select
dShape.Delete
```

But new image is not placed on the previous image position!
What is the problem? 
How can I place new image on exactly on the previous image position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some steps to follow:

**Your old image is still in the position when you are trying to add the new one...so remove the old**...;)

- Save position, size and other properties (`inline with text`,`square`..etc) of old image before deleting
- Delete old image
- insert the new image with `top, left, width, height` and other properites matching the old image's values

Code changes:

```
Dim shp As Shape

'--other codes including the ones that saves properties
dShape.Delete '--hey you don't need to select to delete :)

Set shp = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)_ 
         .Shapes.AddPicture("C:\aa.jpg", False, True, l, t, w, h)
shp.RelativeVerticalPosition = rvp
shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = rhp
shp.LayoutInCell = lic
```